# Is there a way to force an inline embed field on new line in discord.js v12?

Tags: discord.js

I was wondering if it is somehow possible to make '2x2' fields embed. So 2 inline fields next to each other, and under those 2 next 2. If I make all 4 fields inline, it will put 3 into the first line, and the 4th one on the 2nd line. However, if I make the 3rd field not inlined, it is put on a new line, but the 4th one too.
My code:

```
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(guild.name)
        .setColor('#4d648d')
        .addField("Server ID", id, true)
        .addField("Owner", `<@${owner.id}>`, true)
        .addField("Members", `${memberCount} total members`, true)
        .addField("Online members", `${onlineMembers}`, true)
```

This way it gets into the 3 - 1 configuration

```
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(guild.name)
        .setColor('#4d648d')
        .addField("Server ID", id, true)
        .addField("Owner", `<@${owner.id}>`, true)
        .addField("Members", `${memberCount} total members`)
        .addField("Online members", `${onlineMembers}`, true)
```

And this way it gets into 2 - 1 - 1 configuration
Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, no. There is no way to do this in discord.js or Discord. I've even tried making "invisible" fields as a workaround, which just had their names and values set to `** **` and therefore seemed invisible to users, but it didn't fully work as intended and worsened the appearance of the embed. In summary: there is no way to do this currently.

Comment: You could try the invisible fields approach and see if you can get it to work for you, but otherwise there is no other way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I found this question while trying to solve the same issue with `py-cord`, and found that using zero-width space characters worked:

```py
embed.add_field(name="Author", value=message.author.mention, inline=True)
embed.add_field(name="Channel", value=message.channel.mention, inline=True)
embed.add_field(name="\u200B", value="\u200B")  # newline
embed.add_field(name="Date", value=date, inline=True)
embed.add_field(name="Time", value=time, inline=True)
```

[image: Discord embed with 2x2 fields]